# button comes with keyboard how can i fix

Tags: android, scrollview

I used scrollView and outside of scrollView have one button, but when I type in edit text which is inside of scrollVIew then button comes with keyboard, how can I fix this

```
<LinearLayout>
    ......
    ......
    ......

    <ScrollView>
    ......
    <EditText>....1
    <EditText>....2
    <EditText>....3
    <EditText>....4
    <EditText>....5
    <EditText>....6
    <EditText>....7
    <EditText>....8

    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/step1_button_submit"
            style="@style/buttonStyle.RoundCorner.Red.20sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/save" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Because you created "step1_button_submit" as an EditText and not as a Button.

Comment: post the snapshot for the same

Comment: sorry this is button ,i mistaked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your Keyboard to pan instead of resize. You could do that in your AndroidManifest.xml file, for your particular activity, add the below to it

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Comment: this is fragment @Elye

Comment: Just add to your activity that owns the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to hide then:**

```
EditText editTextSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSearch);

InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editTextSearch.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

**If want to show:**

```
EditText editTextSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSearch);
editTextSearch.requestFocus();
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
```